# .net core 3.0 self referencing loop error newtonsoft

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I get this error when I try to some request

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'Company' with type 'ApplicationCore.Entities.IntekManager.Company'. Path
>   'Departments[0]'.

my program.cs

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace Service
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string ProgramName = "TabletMenu";

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel(opt =>
                {
                    opt.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue;
                })
                .UseUrls("http://*:5001")
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

my startup.cs

```
using ApplicationCore.Interfaces;
using Infrastructure.Data;
using Infrastructure.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Service
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

            services.AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationManagerContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ManagerConnection"),
             opt => opt.UseRowNumberForPaging()));

            services.AddScoped(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IDapperRepository<>), typeof(BaseDapperRepository<>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(ProductService));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(TokenService));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(BranchService));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(ProductGroupService));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(FinishedProductService));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(TabletParameterService));
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddTransient(s => s.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
            services.AddTransient(typeof(ConnectionService));

            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddResponseCompression();

            services.AddCors();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseCors(
                options => options
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
            );

            app.UseResponseCompression();

            app.UseMvc();
        }


    }
}
```

I tried these codes but not working still get the error

```
 services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
         .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
         .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

 services.AddControllers()
         .AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

what should I do ?

the controller code is that

```
using ApplicationCore.Entities.IntekManager;
using ApplicationCore.Interfaces;
using Infrastructure.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Service.ViewModels.Account;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Web.Controllers;

namespace Service.Controllers.AccountController
{
    public class AccountController : BaseApiController
    {
        public IAsyncRepository<Company> _companyRepository;
        public IAsyncRepository<Department> _departmentRepository;
        public TokenService _tokenService;

        public AccountController(IAsyncRepository<Company> companyRepository,
            IAsyncRepository<Department> departmentRepository,
            TokenService tokenService)
        {
            _companyRepository = companyRepository;
            _tokenService = tokenService;
            _departmentRepository = departmentRepository;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginTablet([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                var department = await _departmentRepository.FindFilterIncludeAsync(x => x.UserName == model.UserName, x => x.Company);

                if (department == null) return BadRequestResult("Sistemde Böyle Bir Kullanıcı Bulunamadı");

                if (department.Password != model.Password) return BadRequestResult("Şifre Yanlış");

                if (department.LicenceLastTime < DateTime.Now) return BadRequestResult("Lisans Süresi Dolmuş");

                if (!department.Active) return BadRequestResult("Sistem Aktif Değil");

                department.DateResult = department.LicenceLastTime.Day + "/" + department.LicenceLastTime.Month + "/" + department.LicenceLastTime.Year;
                department.RestDay = Math.Round((department.LicenceLastTime - DateTime.Now).TotalDays).ToString() + " GÜN";

                department.Company.CurrentDepartmentName = department.Name;

                department.CompanyName = department.Company.CompanyName;

                return OkResult(new
                {
                    department,
                    token = _tokenService.GetJWTToken(department.Company)
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequestResult("Beklenmedik Bir Hata Meydana Geldii : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Is your controller attempting to return something other than a class you’ve defined?

Comment: i fetched one department data in my controller with including company query then return this data with Ok result but in company data again department and again company by loop thats the problem if return nothing in ok result not error

Comment: Show your code for this please

Comment: i add the controller code

Comment: when i send the department data its return error loop referance but if i wouldnt its not

Comment: Yeah that much I know. Is your class a simple class or does it have complex properties/methods? You might need to control serialization carefully. The code you have up above is largely irrelevant. The error is due to the class you're returning.